# How to disable dedicated GPU in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I want to completely disable my Nvidia GT610m card, and let Ubuntu rely only on the HD4000.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your notebook is wired up (obviously you can't disconnect the monitor cable from a mobile GPU), you may not be able to do this. If you can do it, it wouldn't be from within Ubuntu -- it'd be in the bios.